# Getting items with PodioItem::get() returns number values in wrong format

Tags: php, podio

I am writing an application that can upload values to specific fields in podio. When doing so i have no trouble uploading and receiving text fields, category fields, ect. But when uploading and receiving numbers, they return in the wrong format.

## Example

Uploaded value: `50000`

This will look like this in podio's formatting: `50.000`

When retrieving the field it is formatted like this: `50000.0000`

The field in podio is formatted normally with thousand separators as you can see.

## Example 2

Some of the fields require the formatting to show 2 decimals.

So the uploaded value is `2.24`

In podio this will be formatted like `2,24`

Then when retrieving it returns `2.2400`

## Possible solutions:

- It would be possible to manually format the fields, but the amount of zeros fluctuate. I wouldn't be able to know which zeros the user put.
- A setting to change when retrieving the item?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a numerical value it is stored with 4 decimal places of precision. When that value is rendered in the web ui there is formatting applied. In the examples you provided you are not losing precision and are getting the expected results.